# What are good ways to bring SQL query results into a LaTeX table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, latex, data-visualization, datagrip

**Background**

I'm doing some data analysis on a large dataset on a local PostgreSQL server that I use the DataGrip IDE to query. A substantial proportion of that analysis is tabular stuff: frequency tables and the like which summarize various aspects of key variables.

I do all my writeups in a `LaTeX` environment, which means I'm often bringing stuff over from Postgres (and from `R`, where I do the other part of my analysis) into Tex documents.

**The Problem**

In many cases, I'll try to structure my Postgres queries so that they result in exactly the table I'm looking for.

My question for the community is this: do you guys have favorite, neat, or preferred ways to turn the result of a SQL query into a LaTeX table?

**What I've tried**

Take a simple Postgres database that looks like this:

[image: db]

And say that I wanted a simple table that added up the number of errors for each `id`:

```
select id as "ID", sum(errors) as "Sum of errors"
from d
group by id
```

Yielding something like this in the DataGrip output viewer:

[image: dg_result]

All well and good, but how to get it into LaTeX?

The main way I've tried is functional, but clunky:

1. I use Datagrip's "export data" function next to the output window to copy the table to the clipboard, like so:

[image: clipboard]

2. I then paste it into this website, [Latex Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables), which then spits out some LaTeX code (after I tell the site to add a border around the cells of the table):

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
ID                                            & Sum of errors                                   \\ \hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}a\\ b\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}56\\ 12\end{tabular} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Yielding a neat little result in my document:

[image: result]

So like I said, this is all functional, but since I'm a competent but ultimately quite novice SQL and LaTeX user, I wanted to ask the community whether they had anything better or quicker. Thanks.

(Oh, and let me know if the `Tex` StackExchange is a better place for this. I'd be happy to move it. I actually may cross-post anyway.)

Comment: maybe have a look if anything from https://www.ctan.org/topic/db-access can help you

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a look at `psql`'s `latex` format:

```
test=> \pset format latex
Output format is latex.
test=> SELECT * FROM pg_am;
\begin{tabular}{r | l | l | l}
\textit{oid} & \textit{amname} & \textit{amhandler} & \textit{amtype} \\
\hline
2 & heap & heap\_tableam\_handler & t \\
403 & btree & bthandler & i \\
405 & hash & hashhandler & i \\
783 & gist & gisthandler & i \\
2742 & gin & ginhandler & i \\
4000 & spgist & spghandler & i \\
3580 & brin & brinhandler & i \\
\end{tabular}

\noindent (7 rows) \\
```

Comment: Thanks for this Laurenz, I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Answer (score -1):

LaTeX extractor is not supported yet in DataGrip- follow and upvote the issue [Create LaTeX extractor](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15109).

Extractor can be implemented by yourself as well, follow our [tutorial](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2017/11/08/export-data-in-any-way-with-intellij-based-ides/)

Another option, in case you use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate: use Kotlin data extractor and [script](https://gist.github.com/hfhbd/7ffb4b94e7f9b9035939e26b40999532)